# Excel Power query import csv files

Tags: powerpivot

Hopefully someone can help me with the following question. I want to add one large CSV file (600k rows) every month to the existing ones. What would be the most efficient way (in terms of loading)? Adding the CSV file in a folder and get that whole folder as input for Power Query or somehow use an append query for only the month which is added? Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Michiel

Comment: Do you need this to be done in Excel? You can use the command prompt to append CSV files fairly quickly, [look here](http://webpierat.com/2011/05/23/merging-csv-files-using-the-command-line/).

Power Query can certainly do this too- you simply need to do a one-time append of all your CSV files, and then in the future you will create a query to bring in the new file, and then append it to your master dataset.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! I will check out the site and

Comment: Thanks for your reaction

Answer (score 0):

I would use power query to load the directory of csv files. When a new file is added you just need to "refresh all".

- loading from csv files is the fastest way to load information. (I just read a study and it is incredibly fast, even if there are millions of rows in multiple files)
- you can do any required data cleaning or transformation in the query which is also the fastest way to do manipulations of the data. It is much much faster than making the changes later in excel tables.
- you have the choice of loading into the data model, or to an excel table or both.
- loading the data into the data model makes it available for any use you might have and is extremely useful for creating pivot tables.